# ListPlot with each point a different color and a legend bar

Tags: plotting, graphics, programming, legending

I would like to generate a `ListPlot` with the color for each point in the plot corresponding to a particular value (not associated with the position in the plot). I'd then like to add a legend indicating what the color means.

I'm currently solving the first part of the problem by essentially generating a separate ListPlot for each data point and then assigning a color to that ListPlot. Here's a toy example:

```
n = 5000;
pos = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 2], {n, 2}];
altitude = Norm /@ pos;
ListPlot[{#} & /@ pos, 
 PlotStyle -> ((Blend[{{Min[altitude], Yellow}, {Max[altitude], 
         Red}}, #] &) /@ altitude), AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image]

So my questions are:

(1) Is this the only way to generate such a `ListPlot` (it does the job but it seems inelegant and I suspect it's inefficient, though that's not a big concern for my application)?

(2) Is there an easy way to generate a legend which indicates the value of the color (i.e., a gradient bar which shows the color scale)?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In this case I would use `Point` for plotting the points. For example

```
n = 5000;
pos = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 2], {n, 2}];
altitude = Norm /@ pos;
colorf = Blend[{{Min[altitude], Yellow}, {Max[altitude], Red}}, #] &

pl = Graphics[MapThread[{colorf[#1], Point[#2]} &, {altitude, pos}], 
  Axes -> True, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

As for plotting legends, that's a reoccurring issue in Mathematica. There is a package called  `` PlotLegends` `` which you could try but it is not very user friendly and the legends it produces are quite ugly IMHO. I find that it's often faster to just create a legend by hand. For example, this is a function I use for creating legends with contour plots:

```
plotLegend[{min_, max_}, n_, col_] := 
 Graphics[MapIndexed[{{col[#1], 
      Rectangle[{0, #2[[1]] - 1}, {1, #2[[1]]}]}, {Black, 
      Text[NumberForm[N@#1, {4, 2}], {4, #2[[1]] - .5}, {1, 0}]}} &, 
   Rescale[Range[n], {1, n}, {min, max}]],
  Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> None, PlotRangePadding -> .5]
```

Here, `n` is the number of subdivisions and `col` is the colour function. You could combine the legend with the original plot using `Grid`, e.g.

```
leg = plotLegend[Through[{Min, Max}[altitude]], 20, colorf];
Grid[{{Show[pl, ImageSize -> {Automatic, 300}], 
  Show[leg, ImageSize -> {Automatic, 250}]}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: The numbers on the color legend aren't really nice. You could use `FindDivisions` to get a nice set, like so `FindDivisions[Through[{Min, Max}[altitude]], 10]`

Comment: Very helpful! Many thanks to you and the others who posted answers and suggestions!!!

Comment: WHY are the most minor, simple, obvious things so bloody difficult in MMa?  I've been using MMa for about 6 months now, and this is my zillionth visit to SE to find out how to do something you'd accomplish in 1 line in Mathematica.  Does Wolfram not think about real world use at all???

Answer (score 22):

`ListLinePlot` (or alternately `ListPlot` with `Joined->True`) accepts a `ColorFunction`, which you can use to color your points. The lines can be later converted to points as:

```
colorFun = Function[{x, y}, Blend[{{Min[altitude], Yellow}, {Max[altitude], Red}}, 
    Norm[{x, y}]]];    
ListLinePlot[pos, ColorFunction -> colorFun, AspectRatio -> 1, 
      ColorFunctionScaling -> False] /. Line -> Point
```

Then using Heike's plot legends and Sjoerd's suggestion to use `FindDivisions`, you get:

[image]

Comment: +1 this gets the same faster rendering via `VertexColors` that my code does, but is arguably neater.  I still like `Inset` for the legend; consider combining them.

Comment: @Spartacus Thanks. I will, sometime later in the day. I'm off for now.

Comment: Hi. I am using this code with ListLinePlot but how to modify the point size with the Line->Point command. Thanks.

Comment: @Porty just add `/. {Line -> Point, PointSize[___] -> PointSize[0.02]}` or other value

Answer (score 21):

As usual Heike has a fine method, but I can tighten it up.

This will render quite a bit faster, it will use built-in color functions more easily, and it will IMO interactively rescale better.

Data:

```
n = 5000;
pos = RandomReal[NormalDistribution[0, 2], {n, 2}];
altitude = Norm /@ pos;
colorf = Blend[{Yellow, Red}, #] &;
```

Legend function (modified):

```
plotLegend[{min_, max_}, n_, col_] :=
 Graphics[
  {{col[(# - 1)/(n - 1)], Rectangle[{0, # - 1}, {1, #}]},
   {Black, Text[
      NumberForm[Rescale[#, {1, n}, {min, max}], {4, 2}],
      {3, # - .5}, {1, 0}]}
  } & /@ Range@n,
  Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> None, PlotRangePadding -> .5]
```

Plot:

```
Graphics[{
  Point[pos, VertexColors -> colorf /@ Rescale@altitude],
  Inset[plotLegend[{Min@#, Max@#}& @ altitude, 20, colorf],
    Scaled[{1, 1/2}],
    ImageScaled[{-0.1, 1/2}],
    Scaled[{1/4, 0.9}]]
 }, Axes -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

It's easy to use other gradients.  With `colorf = ColorData["Rainbow"]`:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: As with Heike's solution, yours has an ugly set of numbers. No professional typesetter/layouter would use these. Use `FindDivision` for a better set of numbers.

Comment: @Sjoerd I only noticed this comment now.  Okay, I'll improve this later.

Comment: @Guillochon Thanks for noticing. :-)

Comment: @Sjoerd I see I never did address your criticism.  Sorry.  This time I won't claim that I will, but perhaps; we'll see.

Comment: Can you suggest where/how to insert a small label above the plot legend frame? I've been trying w/o success. A simple framelabel results in unacceptable resizing of the legend.

Comment: @ndetermin Try `Labeled[plotLegend[ . . . ], "label", Top]` and adjust the positioning of `Inset` if necessary.

Comment: Is it possible to do something like this, but for a ListLogLogPlot?

Comment: How can i change the size of the data points? I think i have to use PointSize but not sure where?

Answer (score 4):

```
data = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {50, 3}];
ListPlot[Style[#[[{1, 2}]], Hue@#[[3]]] & /@ data, 
   PlotLegends -> BarLegend[{Hue, {0, 1}}]]
```

Answer (score 3):

### **`BarLegend` and `Legended`:**

Using the setup in Heike's  and Mr.Wizard's answers:

```
n = 5000;
pos = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 2], {n, 2}];
altitude = Norm /@ pos;
colorf = Blend[{{Min[altitude], Yellow}, {Max[altitude], Red}}, #] &;

pl = Graphics[Point[pos, VertexColors -> (colorf /@ altitude)], 
   Axes -> True, AspectRatio -> 1];

bl = BarLegend[{colorf, Through[{Min, Max}[altitude]]}, 10, 
   LegendMarkerSize -> 300, LegendLabel -> Style["legend", 20, "Panel"]];

Legended[pl, Placed[bl, Left]]
```

[image]

To make the bar legend wider postprocess it using the function `makeWide` below:

```
ClearAll[makeWide]
makeWide[w_: 15] := RawBoxes[ToBoxes[#] /. {15/2 | 7.5 ->  w/2, -15/2 | (-7.5) -> -w/2}]&;

Legended[pl, makeWide[40]@bl]
```

[image]