# Coloring Points in a List Plot

Tags: plotting, graphics, color

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ListPlot with each point a different color and a legend bar](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1300/listplot-with-each-point-a-different-color-and-a-legend-bar)

I want to color the points in a list plot using a function of the (x,y) values.

I tried this (example with random data):

```
ListPlot[RandomReal[1, {100, 2}],
 PlotStyle -> Thick,
 Joined -> False,
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue[(x + y)/2]]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But, apparently, `ColorFunction` requires the data to be joined.

```
ListPlot[RandomReal[1, {100, 2}],
 PlotStyle -> Thick,
 Joined -> True,
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue[(x + y)/2]]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

That's a big ugly mess that I don't want. How can I get the points colored without joining them, am I missing something simple here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One way is to use `Joined -> True` and replace `Line` with `Point` afterwards:

```
ListPlot[RandomReal[1, {100, 2}], PlotStyle -> Thick, Joined -> True, 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue[(x + y)/2]]] /. Line[a__] :> Point[a]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: +1 -- any reason not to replace `Line` with `Point` directly? `/. Line -> Point`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard No reason whatsoever apart from me being a bit dim today.

Comment: I noticed that all of the points in your image are actually small squares.  Why is that?

Answer (score 15):

I propose using `Graphics` primitives:

```
data = RandomReal[1, {1000, 2}];

Graphics[{Thick, Point[data, VertexColors -> (Hue /@ Mean /@ data)]},
 AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio,
 Axes -> True
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Here's another method that does not perform as well, but I like the style:

```
ListPlot[List /@ data, BaseStyle -> Thick, PlotStyle -> (Hue /@ Mean /@ data)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Do you not think this is a duplicate of the question linked above? The answers are exactly the same by the same users...

Comment: @R.M hm... I guess I saw that question as being focused on the harder problem of the legend bar.  This one is much simpler.  I'll be in Chat.

Answer (score 10):

Questions on here tend to be asked and answered by morning in my timezone but

Mr Wizard: "*I noticed that all of the points in your image are actually small squares. Why is that?*"

Some sort of visual artifact when point sizes are small. To modify you could just include a point size in the rule replacement:

```
ListLinePlot[RandomReal[1, {1000, 2}], 
  ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y}, Hue[(x + y)/2]]] /. 
 Line[a__] :> {AbsolutePointSize[8], Point[a]}
```

[image]

Comment: I ended up using `{PointSize[Medium], Point[a]}`

Answer (score 7):

Here's another route:

```
ListPlot[RandomReal[1, {100, 2}], PlotStyle -> Thick] /. Point[{v1_, v2__}] :>
   Map[{Apply[Function[{x, y}, Hue[(x + y)/2]], #], Point[#]} &, {v1, v2}]
```

[image: colorful points]

Prompted by Mr. Wizard's fine answer, here is yet another method:

```
ListPlot[RandomReal[1, {100, 2}], PlotStyle -> Thick] /. Point[pts_] :> 
  Point[pts, VertexColors -> Function[{x, y}, Hue[(x + y)/2]] @@@ pts]
```