# Project RegionPlot3D to 2D using hue/color function to show third dimension

Tags: plotting

I would like to project the output of RegionPlot3D onto a 2D plane.  Basically I'd like to turn this

```
f = a^2  + b^3 + c;
RegionPlot3D[f <= 0.5, {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}, {c, 0, 1}, 
 AxesLabel -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 ViewPoint -> Above, Mesh -> None]
```

into something more like a contour plot (colour showing what the c value is).  I am only interested in the maximum value for c that will satisfy the constraints - so I would like to project onto a 2D plane.

My actual functions are considerably more complex, and the 3D image makes it harder to see the detail.

Comment: Can you always solve for `a`, `b`, or `c`, or are they trapped in a complicated implicit relationship?

Comment: Complicated implicit relationships unfortunately.  There are also multiple conditions within the Region plot to ensure what is returned is physical as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This post https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21726/34694 gave me the solution - essentially set the z-axis viewpoint to infinity and you will have a 2D projection.

```
f = a^2 + b^3 + c;
RegionPlot3D[f <= 0.5, {a, 0, 1}, {b, 0, 1}, {c, 0, 1}, 
 AxesLabel -> Automatic, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
 ViewPoint -> {0, 0, Infinity}, Mesh -> None, 
 Axes -> {True, True, False}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Edit: Note that removing the AxesLabel -> Automatic, gets rid of the z axis label issue in the bottom left hand corner

Comment: You could also combine these two options `...ViewPoint -> Top, ViewProjection -> "Orthographic"...` to get the same effect.