# How can I make a projection of ParametricPlot3D onto 2D surface without shading?

Tags: plotting, graphics3d, color, parametric-functions

I have a Parametric Plot that has very high and low values.
I used this answer [Project RegionPlot3D to 2D using hue/color function to show third dimension](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/194025/project-regionplot3d-to-2d-using-hue-color-function-to-show-third-dimension) to project the surface onto the 2D plane. This is the code:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{u, v, Exp[u]*Cos[u - v]}, {u, 1, 3}, {v, 1, 5}, 
 Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> {0, 0, Infinity}, Axes -> False, 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", Mesh -> None, Background -> Black]
```

However when I do that the resulting image seems to still have the shading which is what I want to avoid.
I also would like to change the color function so that the color function goes from white to a darker orange going through shade of orange only.

Answer (score 3):

You could follow [this example](https://wolfram.com/xid/0ftw0hm-6g4x6) from the documentation and use `Glow`:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{u, v, Exp[u]*Cos[u - v]}, {u, 1, 3}, {v, 1, 5}, 
 Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> {0, 0, Infinity}, Axes -> False, 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, z}, Glow[ColorData["TemperatureMap", z]]], 
 Mesh -> None, Lighting -> None]
```

[image]

Here is an example of adjusting the range of colors to be white to orange:

```
ParametricPlot3D[{u, v, Exp[u]*Cos[u - v]}, {u, 1, 3}, {v, 1, 5}, 
 Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> {0, 0, Infinity}, Axes -> False, 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y, z}, 
   Glow[ColorData["TemperatureMap", 
     Rescale[z, {-10, 20}, {0.5, 0.95}]]]], 
 ColorFunctionScaling -> False, Mesh -> None, Lighting -> None]
```

[image: ColorFunctionScaling False example]

Comment: Thank you!! I actually tried to use glow but i was missing the z, I didn't know how to make it work

Answer (score 3):

You could use white ambient light and a custom `ColorFunction` based on a `Blend` of `White` and `Darker@Orange`.

```
ParametricPlot3D[{u, v, Exp[u]*Cos[u - v]}, {u, 1, 3}, {v, 1, 5}
 , Boxed -> False
 , ViewPoint -> {0, 0, Infinity}
 , Axes -> False
 , ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, u, v}, Blend[{White, Darker@Orange}, z]]
 , Mesh -> None
 , Background -> Black
 , Lighting -> {"Ambient", White}
]
```

[image: ParametricPlot3D + ambient lighting + white->dark orange blended color function]

Comment: Thanks! :) this was very helful

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the option [`NormalsFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NormalsFunction.html):

```
ParametricPlot3D[{u, v, Exp[u] Cos[u - v]}, {u, 1, 3}, {v, 1, 5}, 
 Boxed -> False,
 ViewPoint -> {0, 0, ∞}, 
 Axes -> False, 
 Mesh -> None, 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap", 
 NormalsFunction -> ({1, 1, 0} &)]
```

[image]

Use `ColorFunction -> (Blend[{White, Orange}, #3] &)` (as in Josh Bishop's answer) we get:

[image]

Use `ColorFunction -> (Blend[{White, Yellow, Red}, #3] &)` to get

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! the colors you put are perfect for what I needed