# Controlling colors of points in ListPlot

Tags: graphics, color, plotting

I have a collection of points I want to plot using ListPlot[]. I would like each individual point to be a certain color depending on a key value that is based on a list separate from the points. As a simple example suppose we have list={1,2,3,4} and keys={7,8,9,10}. If keys[[i]] is odd we want list[[i]] to be black, if keys[[i]] is even we want list[[i]] to be red. How can I do this?

Comment: Is [Coloring Points in a Plot, based on their position in the list](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21130/coloring-points-in-a-plot-based-on-their-position-in-the-list), [Coloring Points in a List Plot](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5185/coloring-points-in-a-list-plot) of some help?

Comment: @Lou I looked at these, it was not obvious how to adapt them to my problem. In my problem the color of the point in the plotted list is controlled by a boolean value compute based on an element in a second list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 4} ; keys = {7, 8, 9, 10};
styleddata = Style[#, {Black, Red}[[Mod[#2, 2, 1]]]] & @@@ Transpose[{list, keys}];
```

Or

```
styleddata = Style[#, If[OddQ@#2, Black, Red]] & @@@ Transpose[{list, keys}];
styleddata = Style[#, #2 Black + (1 - #2) Red] & @@@Transpose[{list, Boole@OddQ@keys}];

ListPlot[styleddata, BaseStyle -> PointSize[Large]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Just use a color function that you can map over your keys

```
keyList = {1, 2, 3};
keys = RandomChoice[keyList, 10];(*Dummy keys*)
pts = RandomInteger[100, {Length@keys, 2}];(*Dummy Points*)
colors[key_] := Hue[key/Length@keyList];(*A color function that you can modify*)

ListPlot[
  Transpose@{pts},
  PlotStyle -> colors /@ keys
]
```

[image: Points colored by key]