# Color each data point

Tags: plotting, color

I want to color each point in [`ListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html) using custom markers when there are only values of the points, i.e. the data is in the form `{1,2,3,...}`. There are many related questions (e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22893242) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/80395/44141)), but the solutions are either to use data in the form `{x,y}`, convert it to the list of lists, and then effectively color each subplot separately

```
data1 = {{{1, 2}, Red}, {{2, 3}, Blue}};
ListPlot[
   List /@ data1[[;; , 1]], 
   PlotMarkers -> 
      Apply[Graphics[{#, Rectangle[]}, ImageSize -> 15] &, List /@ data1[[;; , 2]], {1}]
]
```

or to color each point using [`Style`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Style.html), in which case using custom markers doesn't work.

```
data2 = {Style[2, Red], Style[3, Blue]};
ListPlot[data2, PlotMarkers -> Graphics[{Rectangle[]}, ImageSize -> 15]]
```

Is there a solution when the data doesn't have the `x` coordinate?

Comment: Why it's a problem to add `x` coordinate?

Comment: @swish it isn't, but I'm interested in a more general solution, that doesn't require inserting dummy coordinates. If anything, `DataRange` doesn't work with `x` inserted, so you will need a new workaround there and so on.

Comment: Why didn't put the requirement that you wanted to specify the data range in your question? Very bad form not to do that.

Comment: @m_goldberg Well, data range was just an example, I was thinking in more general terms when something else might not work as well. For my particular example, this will work, but the idea was to understand a more universal approach.

Comment: The universal approach is to write a custom function.

Comment: @m_goldberg This is what I wanted, I just thought it might be done for a particular representation of data, if there are two options to feed the data. The solution with x still seems to be a hack, but I agree that as long as it works, we can use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm with swish. I think it's easy to add the x-coordinate.

```
data = {{2, Red}, {3, Blue}, {1, Green}};
Module[{pts, markers},
  pts = MapThread[{{#1, #2}} &, {Range @ Length[data], data[[All, 1]]}];
  markers = 
    Graphics[{#, Rectangle[]}, ImageSize -> 15] & @@@ List /@ data[[All, 2]];
  ListPlot[pts, PlotMarkers -> markers]]
```

[image: plot]

#### Update

If you want  to specify the plot range, then define a custom version of `ListPlot`. Like so:

```
myListPlot[data_, min_, max_] :=
  Module[{xcoords, pts, markers},
    xcoords = Subdivide[min, max, Length[data] - 1];
    pts = MapThread[{{#1, #2}} &, {xcoords, data[[All, 1]]}];
    markers = 
      Graphics[{#, Rectangle[]}, ImageSize -> 15] & @@@ List /@ data[[All, 2]];
    ListPlot[pts, PlotMarkers -> markers]]

myListPlot[data, 10, 20]
```

[image: plot]

plot

Comment: Makes sense. I tend to agree it is a good solution using x coordinate. There might be other options that wouldn't work, but I will leave those cases to future questions.