# Why Map needs to be evaluated inside ListPlot?

Tags: plotting, evaluation

This is unrelated to my [previous question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/136458/44141), but is based on it. The following example works fine:

```
data1 = {{{1, 2}, Red}, {{2, 3}, Blue}};
ListPlot[
 List /@ data1[[;; , 1]], 
 PlotMarkers -> 
  Apply[Graphics[{#, Rectangle[]}, ImageSize -> 15] &, 
   List /@ data1[[;; , 2]], {1}]
 ]
```

If we replace it, however, with

```
ListPlot[
 List /@ data1[[;; , 1]], 
 PlotMarkers -> Graphics[{#, Rectangle[]}, ImageSize -> 15] & /@ data1[[;; , 2]]
 ]
```

It doesn't work -- colors are the same. This can be fixed using [`Evaluate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Evaluate.html)

```
ListPlot[List /@ data1[[;; , 1]], 
 PlotMarkers -> 
  Evaluate@(Graphics[{#, Rectangle[]}, ImageSize -> 15] & /@ data1[[;; , 2]])
 ]
```

Now we can suspect that [`ListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html) has [`HoldAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAll.html)
 attributes, so we everything that needs to be evaluated (and [`Map`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Map.html) [does](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/46248/44141)) will be held. However, unlike [`Plot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html), [`ListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html) doesn't have the [`HoldAll`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HoldAll.html) attribute

```
Plot // Attributes
ListPlot // Attributes
```

> {HoldAll, Protected, ReadProtected}
>
> {Protected, ReadProtected}

So, what's happening here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

& has very low precedence, so you need to include parentheses, e.g.:

> PlotMarkers -> (Graphics[{#, Rectangle[]}, ImageSize -> 15] &) /@ data1[[;; , 2]]

Comment: Wow! I didn't know this. Seems so subtle. So, `Evaluate` overrides this default precedence?

Comment: The `(` after your `Evaluate` does that.