# How to speed up ListPlot when each point has its own color

Tags: plotting, performance-tuning

I have a list of (x,y) points I would like to plot with each point a specific color. ListPlot is substantially slower when I assign each point a color than when I use the default single color for each point.

Any idea on how to speed up?

Below is test code where I have assigned one of four colors randomly. Note the timing.

Thanks.

```
n = 10^4;
locs = Table[{RandomReal[] , RandomReal[]} , n];
c = RandomChoice [ {Red, Green, Blue, Black} , n];
t0 = TimeUsed[];
p1 = ListPlot[locs, ImageSize -> 800];
t1 = TimeUsed[];
p2 = ListPlot[List /@ locs, ImageSize -> 800, PlotStyle -> c];
t2 = TimeUsed[];
Print [ "All same color = ", t1 - t0 , " cpu seconds." ];
Print["Each point its own color = " , t2 - t1 , " cpu seconds." ];
```

All same color = 0.115 cpu seconds.
Each point its own color = 7.015 cpu seconds

Comment: Note: you can use `Timing` (or `AbsoluteTiming`) to measure how much time it takes to execute some command. For example, `p1 = ListPlot[locs, ImageSize -> 800]; // AbsoluteTiming` yields `0.1` seconds and `p2 = ListPlot[List /@ locs, ImageSize -> 800, PlotStyle -> c]; // AbsoluteTiming` yields `9.3` seconds. No need to use that `t0 = 
 TimeUsed[];` trickery.

Comment: What about `Graphics[Point[locs, VertexColors -> c], Options@ListPlot]`?  What you lose is automatic `PointSize[]` determination....

Comment: FWIW the trick of coloring the data https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/80403/2079 turns out to be extremely slow..

Answer (score 9):

`VertexColors` is an efficient way.  You can use it with `p1` as follows (it adds very little time):

```
p4 = p1 /. Point[p_] :> Point[p, VertexColors -> c]; // AbsoluteTiming
p4

(*  {0.000087, Null}  *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can also apply it directly in `Graphics`, although you lose the automatic `PointSize[]` control:

```
Graphics[Point[locs, VertexColors -> c], Options@ListPlot]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 6):

How about this. Not fancy but fast. Make sure `n` is divisible by 4 which is # of colors.

```
n = 10^4;
locs = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {n, 2}];
locs2 = Partition[locs, n/4];
ListPlot[locs]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.107778

```
Show[ListPlot[locs2[[1]], PlotStyle -> {Red}], 
    ListPlot[locs2[[2]], PlotStyle -> {Green}], 
    ListPlot[locs2[[3]], PlotStyle -> {Blue}], 
    ListPlot[locs2[[4]], PlotStyle -> {Black}]]; // 
  AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 0.158271

[image]

```
n = 10^4;
locs = Table[{RandomReal[], RandomReal[]}, n];
c = RandomChoice[{Red, Green, Blue, Black}, n];
p2 = ListPlot[List /@ locs, ImageSize -> 800, PlotStyle -> c]; // 
  AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 7.67799

Comment: Since the OP raises the specific question of timing, perhaps you ought to time this and compare?

Comment: Sure, I'll be edit it.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder about AbsoluteTiming. As usual, there;'s always a more elegant way to learn.  The Partitioning works but I should have been clearer that in the actual application, the colors have meaning as opposed to the random assignment I made for the example. In other words, each point is one of four colors for a specific reason so I need to carry that info along.

Comment: note this approach can be automated as `ListPlot[#[[All, All, 1]],PlotStyle -> #[[All, 1, 2]]] &@GatherBy[Transpose[{locs, c}], #[[2]] &]`  (with `c` as in original post )

Comment: And with @george2079 's code, it's not dependent on a prescribed structure and correspondence of the data and colors, but seems more fitting with the OP's original formulation of the problem.