# Color-code edges by order in edge list

Tags: plotting, graphs-and-networks

Given a graph with vertex coordinates list V and edge list E, how can I visualize the order of appearance of edges in E? It is similar to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5185/coloring-points-in-a-list-plot) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7127729/color-plot-by-order-of-points-in-list-mathematica) question which ask how to color-code points in a point plot by color. It does not matter to me if the output is a graph, plot, etc. as long as the edge ordering is encoded somehow.

Answer (score 4):

```
ClearAll[edgeColorList, legends]
edgeColorList[cf_ : Automatic][g_Graph] := 
   Switch[cf, 
     Automatic, ColorData[97] /@ Range[EdgeCount[g]], 
     _String, ColorData[{cf, {1, EdgeCount@g}}] /@ Range[EdgeCount[g]], 
    _Integer, ColorData[cf] /@ Range[EdgeCount[g]], 
    _, cf]; 

legends[cf_ : Automatic][g_Graph] := Grid[Transpose @
   Prepend[{ "index  ", "edge  ", "color  "}]@
     Transpose[{EdgeIndex[g, #] & /@ EdgeList[g], EdgeList[g], 
      Graphics[{#, Disk[{0, 0}, Offset[10]]}, ImageSize -> 20] & /@ 
        edgeColorList[cf][g]}], 
    Spacings -> 1];
```

***Examples:***

```
SeedRandom[1];
rg = RandomGraph[BernoulliGraphDistribution[9, 0.4]]
```

[image]

Use default colors (`ColorData[97]`):

```
SetProperty[rg, {EdgeLabels -> Placed["Index", .4], 
    EdgeStyle -> {e_ :> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[5], Opacity[1], 
        edgeColorList[][rg][[EdgeIndex[rg, e]]]]}, 
    PlotLabel -> legends[][rg], ImageSize -> Large, 
    VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], VertexSize -> Medium}]
```

[image]

Shuffle edges of `rg`:

```
SeedRandom[1];
rg2 = Graph @ RandomSample @ EdgeList @ rg;

SetProperty[#, {EdgeLabels -> Placed["Index", .4], 
   EdgeStyle -> {e_ :> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[5], Opacity[1], 
        edgeColorList[][#][[EdgeIndex[#, e]]]]}, 
   PlotLabel -> legends[][#], ImageSize -> Large, 
   VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], VertexSize -> Medium}] & @ rg2
```

[image]

Use `ColorData["Rainbow"]`:

```
SetProperty[#, {EdgeLabels -> Placed["Index", .4], 
    EdgeStyle -> {e_ :> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[5], Opacity[1], 
          edgeColorList["Rainbow"][#][[EdgeIndex[#, e]]]]}, 
    PlotLabel -> legends["Rainbow"][#], ImageSize -> Large, 
    VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], VertexSize -> Medium}] & @ rg2
```

[image]

Use a list of colors to specify the edge styles:

```
SeedRandom[1];
colors = RandomColor[EdgeCount @ rg];

SetProperty[#, {EdgeLabels -> Placed["Index", .4], 
     EdgeStyle -> {e_ :> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[5], Opacity[1], 
            edgeColorList[colors][#][[EdgeIndex[#, e]]]]}, 
     PlotLabel -> legends[colors][#], ImageSize -> Large, 
     VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center], VertexSize -> Medium}] & @ rg2
```

[image]

**Note:** In versions 12.0+, you can replace [`SetProperty`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetProperty.html) above with [`Annotate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Annotate.html).

Alternatively, if you start with a list of edges and colors, you can use

```
edges = EdgeList[rg2];

Graph[MapThread[Style,
   {edges, Directive[AbsoluteThickness[5], Opacity[1], #]& /@ colors}], 
   EdgeLabels -> Placed["Index", .4],
   VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Center],
   VertexSize -> Medium, 
   ImageSize -> Large]
```

> same picture

You can replace `Style` with `Property[#, EdgeStyle -> #2]&` to get the same picture.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, you want to colour each edge based on its position in the edge list. With [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM/),

```
Needs["IGraphM`"]

g = RandomGraph[{10, 20}]

Graph[g, GraphStyle -> "ThickEdge"] // 
 IGEdgeMap[ColorData["Rainbow"], EdgeStyle -> Rescale@*Range@*EdgeCount]
```

[image]