# How can I convert this ListPlot to ArrayPlot?

Tags: plotting

I want to rewrite this code with `ArrayPlot`,

```
n = 10;
eqs = x^Range[0, n - 1].# & /@ Tuples[{-1, 1}, n];
g = ListPlot[{Re@#, Im@#} & /@ Flatten[x /. NSolve /@ eqs]]
```

[image]

just like

```
ListPlot[Reap[
   Do[If[x^2 + y^2 < 500, Sow@{x, y}], 
      {x, -100, 100}, {y, -100, 100}]][[2, 1]], AspectRatio -> 1]
```

can be written

```
ArrayPlot[
 Table[If[x^2 + y^2 < 500, 1, 0], {x, -100, 100}, {y, -100, 100}]]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Why would someone do this? Your initial points are on real valued positions, while a raster for `ArrayPlot` have fixed pixel positions. You will loose information that way!

Comment: Play around a bit with `BinCounts` and `MatrixPlot`

Comment: @halirutan, I think `ArrayPlot` worked more faster and easy to set `ColorFunction`.

Comment: If your question is about setting the `ColorFunction` to the `ListPlot`, this is a duplicate of this: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1300/5

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
n = 10;
eqs = x^Range[0, n - 1].# & /@ Tuples[{-1, 1}, n];
data={Re@#,Im@#}&/@Flatten[x/.NSolve/@eqs];
dataBin=Sign@Transpose@BinCounts[data,{-2,2,0.01},{-2,2,0.01}]
ArrayPlot[dataBin]
```

We get:

[image]

Now playing a little with new Mathematica 9 `Image3D`, we get it rendered for each n, from 1 to 10:

```
data3D=Table[
    eqs=x^Range[0,n-1].#&/@Tuples[{-1,1},n];
    data={Re@#,Im@#}&/@Flatten[x/.NSolve/@eqs];
    Sign@Transpose@BinCounts[data,{-2,2,0.01},{-2,2,0.01}]
,{n,1,10}]//Quiet;

Image3D[data3D, BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 1}]
```

[image: image2]

Much more cool! :)

Comment: @chyanog Hi! Thank you for the accept.

Answer (score 6):

I would not use `ArrayPlot` because it expects a matrix while you have free point positions. In the processing of pressing the real valued positions on a grid, you will lose information.

Regarding your comment:

> @halirutan, I think ArrayPlot worked more faster and easy to set ColorFunction.

When your goal is to colorize your points and you *think* setting the `ColorFunction` in `ListPlot` is too slow, why don't you plot your points manually? I assume doing something like

```
n = 10;
eqs = x^Range[0, n - 1].# & /@ Tuples[{-1, 1}, n];
data = {Re@#, Im@#} & /@ Flatten[x /. NSolve /@ eqs];

Graphics[Point[data]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

can never be slower than calling `ListPlot`. Now you want to colorize each point which means you want to transform a point `{x,y}` into a color like `{r,g,b}`. Let's say you try to make this function as fast as possible, because it is called very often with many points. Therefore, you use `Compile` in a parallel fashion. One simple example would be

```
colfunc = Compile[{{point, _Real, 1}},
  .5*{Sin[point[[1]]], -Sin[point[[2]]], Cos[point[[2]]]} + .5,
  Parallelization -> True, RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}
  ]
```

And then you see that you can give a list of colors to `Point`, colorizing each point differently when you use the option `VertexColors`:

```
Graphics[Point[data, VertexColors -> colfunc[data]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This runs in no time compared to your `NSolve` call, which is about **1000 times slower**!