# Coloring the points in a ListPlot with the value of another function

Tags: plotting, color

I'm a relative beginner in *Mathematica*, but after reading the forums for a long time, I couldn't understand one thing:

- I want to plot a list `h`. Let's call it `ListPlot[h]`
- I also have a second list, of the same size `c`
- I want to write a color function that plots a given point in `h` with a color corresponding to the value of `c` at the same point.

Anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: Related question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1300/listplot-with-each-point-a-different-color-and-a-legend-bar

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps it's better to use `Graphics` where you have full control over all aspects of the plot:

```
h = RandomReal[10, {10, 2}];
c = ColorData[1, "ColorList"][[1 ;; 10]];
Graphics[{PointSize[Medium], #[[1]], Point[#[[2]]]} & /@ Transpose[{c, h}], Axes -> True]
```

[image: listplot]

Regarding your comment, you could do something like this:

```
h = RandomReal[10, 20];
c = RandomReal[10, 20];

(* You have to give each y value a corresponding x value *)
h = MapIndexed[{First@#2, #} &, h];

(* You have to normalize the concentration so it works with the color function. *)
c = Normalize[c];

colorfunc = ColorData["SolarColors"];

Graphics[{PointSize[Medium], colorfunc@#[[1]], Point[#[[2]]]} & /@ Transpose[{c, h}], Axes -> True]
```

It's the same idea, but we don't assume that the x coordinate of each point is its position in the list. We also don't assume a list of colors, but rather think of that list as a list of concentration levels.

I noticed now that in m_goldberg's answer he sets the `AspectRatio` to `1/GoldenRatio`, this is an excellent idea since it looks good and is the default aspect ratio for plots in MMA. I too recommend that.

Comment: @Edouard, for a large number of points I would suggest using a gradient color scheme, for example: `c = ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ (Range[25]/25);`

Comment: Thanks a lot ! But actually, what I want to do is not to plot one function as a function of the other. I would like h to be a [1xn] list, and simply plot the n values of "h". But then, to have the values of "h" colorcoded according to the values of "c" at the same x-axis value (without actually plotting "c"). Basically, I want to look at the profile of a a physical interface which has some concentration of molecule at every point. And I would like the interface h(x) to be red (for instance) in regions where the concentration c(x) is high ? Thanks again !

Comment: @Edouard I added something I think should meet your needs.

Answer (score 2):

I think Pickett is right to use `Graphics`, but here is how I would implement it, step-by-step.

Make some data

```
SeedRandom[42];
h = RandomInteger[42, 12];
c = Table[Hue[i/Length[h]], {i, 0, Length[h] - 1}];
```

Make the points.

```
pts = Point /@ Transpose[{Range[Length[h]], h}]
```

Color the points.

```
coloredPts = Transpose[{c, pts}];
```

Make a plot with 'Graphics`.

```
Graphics[{PointSize[Medium], coloredPts},
  Axes -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

[image: plot.png]