# Using colorData and BarLegend in ListPlot

Tags: plotting, legending

I read lot of questions about this issue, mainly: 
[the stack code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1300/listplot-with-each-point-a-different-color-and-a-legend-bar)

So,I tried  create a list plot with bar legend , using the following code:

```
    ListPlot[List /@ rad[[All, 1 ;; 2]], AxesOrigin -> {0, -90}, 
 DataRange -> {{0, 360}, {-90, 90}}, Frame -> True, 
 BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Kartika", 12}, 
 FrameLabel -> {"RA (\[Degree])", "DEC (\[Degree])"}, 
 PlotStyle -> ({PointSize[0.002], ColorData["Rainbow"][#/85]} & /@ 
    rad[[All, 3]]), AspectRatio -> 1, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  Placed[BarLegend[{"Rainbow"}, LegendMargins -> {{0, 0}, {10, 5}}, 
    LegendLabel -> "Geocentric Velocity [km/seg]", 
    LegendFunction -> "Panel", 
    LabelStyle -> {Italic, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"}], Above]]
```

using the data:

```
a = RandomReal[360, {1000}];
b = RandomReal[90, {1000}];
c = RandomReal[90, {1000}];
rad = Transpose[{a, b, c}];
```

It worked fine, but the legendbar did not , it just does not appear, only the plotting.

What did I do wrong?

EDIT 1:

The new code with some suggested modifications:

```
 ListPlot[List /@ rad[[All, 1 ;; 2]], AxesOrigin -> {0, -90}, 
     DataRange -> {{0, 360}, {-90, 90}}, Frame -> True,  
     FrameLabel -> {"RA (\[Degree])", "DEC (\[Degree])"}, 
     PlotStyle -> ({PointSize[0.002], ColorData["Rainbow"][#/85]} & /@ 
        rad[[All, 3]]), AspectRatio -> 1, 
     PlotLegends -> 
      Placed[BarLegend["Rainbow", LegendMargins -> {{0, 0}, {10, 5}}, 
        LegendLabel -> "Geocentric Velocity [km/seg]", 
        LegendFunction -> "Panel"] Above]]
```

The resulting plot:

I used the actually data,  more than 3.500 points with also negative declinations points (I preferred not using them  in this question, as the final LegendBar would be the same using the sample of random data).

[image: The plotting]

And a complement question:

why is the range  in bar not 0 -> 90.0?

Comment: Could you attach the actual plot you obtain?  Thanks.

Comment: Please pare your code down to the minimal example that illustrates your problem.  You don't need FontFamily -> "Kartika" for example.  This will help us help you.

Comment: Oh sorry, I will do this

Comment: The range is `{0,90}` now.  I made the edit when I saw your earlier Comment, which now appears to be gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fix is a simple one.  Replace `{"Rainbow"}` by `{"Rainbow", {0, 90}}` to produce

[image]