# 2D scatter plot with colorbar legend and point size variation

Tags: plotting, graphics

I want to represent a 4-dimension data ({{x1},{x2}, {x3}, {y}}) using 2D scatter plot with color and point size variation. I make some initial trying based on [2D scatter plot with color bar legend](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1300/listplot-with-each-point-a-different-color-and-a-legend-bar?lq=1)

Below is the code, I got the point size variation but lost the color variation of the data points. Could somebody help me? Thanks a lot. P.S. Do not need to worry about the position of the color bar.

```
x1 = RandomReal[10, 100];
x2 = RandomReal[10, 100]; 
x3 = RandomReal[10, 100] + 2;
y = RandomReal[10, 100];

plotLegend[{min_, max_}, n_, col_] := 
 Graphics[{{col[(# - 1)/(n - 1)], 
      Rectangle[{0, # - 1}, {1, #}]}, {Black, 
      Text[NumberForm[
        Rescale[#, {1, n}, {min, max}], {3, 1}], {3, # - .5}, {1, 
        0}]}} & /@ Range@n, Frame -> True, Background -> White, 
  FrameTicks -> None, FrameLabel -> {"", "", "x3", ""}, 
  PlotRangePadding -> .5]

colorf = Blend[{Orange, Blue}, #] &; 
pP = Graphics[{{Table[{PointSize[(x2[[i]] + 5)/500], 
      Point[{x1[[i]], y[[i]]}]}, {i, 1, Length@x1}], 
    VertexColors -> colorf /@ Rescale@(x3)}, 
   Inset[plotLegend[{Min@#, Max@#} &@x3, 6, colorf], 
    Scaled[{0.7, 0.30}], ImageScaled[{0.1, 1/2}], 
    Scaled[{1/3, 0.6}]]}, PlotRange -> {All, {0, 12}}, Axes -> None, 
  Frame -> True, GridLines -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> 0.8, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x1", "y"}]
```

Answer (score 3):

Just put the colours in the `Graphics[Table[]]`

```
Graphics[{{Table[{PointSize[(x2[[i]] + 5)/
       500], (colorf /@ Rescale@(x3))[[i]], 
     Point[{x1[[i]], y[[i]]}]}, {i, 1, Length@x1}]}, 
  Inset[plotLegend[{Min@#, Max@#} &@x3, 6, colorf], 
   Scaled[{0.7, 0.30}], ImageScaled[{0.1, 1/2}], Scaled[{1/3, 0.6}]]},
  PlotRange -> {All, {0, 12}}, Axes -> None, Frame -> True, 
 GridLines -> Automatic, AspectRatio -> 0.8, 
 FrameLabel -> {"x1", "y"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is exactly what I want!