# Changing colors with parameter

Tags: plotting, color

I have the following code:

```
data = {};
Do[AppendTo[data, Reap[(...)]], {k, 0, 10, 0.5}];
ListPlot[data, ImageSize -> Full]
```

I'm collecting points with a changing parameter `k`. How can I change the brightness or the color of the points collected with a specific `k` according to the value of `k`?

Comment: You might need to be a bit more specific about what's going on in the `...` part of your code to get a useful answer.

Comment: See, for instance, the answers to [question 1300](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1300/1063).

Comment: Are you sure that you indeed need to vary the brightness, rather than, say, a color? I mean that a slight change of the brightness may be noticeable not enough.  If you are sure about the brightness, have a look at the `LCHColor`: Menu/Help/WolframDocumentation/LCHColor. This might help.